# golang: gzip or zlib compression of byte array sporadically hangs

Tags: arrays, go, gzip, zlib

I have the following function to compress a byte array:

```
func compress(input []byte) []byte {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        compr := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
        compr.Write(input) // here it appears to hang until
                           // Enter is pressed
        compr.Close()
        output := buf.Bytes()

        return output
}
```

Sporadically the function will hang. When I press [Enter] the function will continue and return the expected result. Am I missing something here?

It will hang about one times out of five, even when the same input is given. Whether I use gzip or zlib, it doesn't matter.

I am using go 1.6 on Linux x86_64

Comment: You really should get into the habit of checking errors. Are you sure your code hangs and not just your terminal isn't refreshed?

Comment: @icza: I've added a print statement after each line to check. Sometimes it will only print the statement immediately following `compr := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)`. The terminal is not hanging; the cursor will blink eagerly until I press Enter, which happens to be fed into the next function that expects user input. Is there any other way to check for errors in this particular case?

Comment: Can you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still produces your issue?

Comment: @icza: not needed. You pointed me into the right direction. Using a different terminal emulator (konsole), I could not reproduce the error. The erroneous terminal is terminator. Your first guess happened to be the right one. - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not the code's or golang's fault. The terminal emulator I used (terminator) did not refresh properly, it seems. Using a different terminal emulator I could not reproduce the error.